# Text alignment in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

For any text in the firefox broswer, I am getting unwanted space below text. Does anyone know how to remove it? The text is perfect in Chrome. I need a solution that would work across all browsers. Thanks.

```html
<style>
  .text {
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>

<p class="text">Hello World</p>
```

Screenshot of Issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysOsU.jpg

Comment: Can you provide screen shot of both chrome and Firefox with highlighted space problem

Comment: I see the same thing in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Did you try to add letters like `jpq` and `ÄÂË` ? that space is reseverd for them

Comment: set line-height:50px;.. it will remove some of the spaces

Comment: @Sethuraman I have put a link to a screenshot in the original post.

Comment: For me i am getting same in both browser , Please change the font-family that you using and check.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the margins to 0 too?

```
<style>
  .text {
    border: 2px solid red;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Yes that doesn't work. The extra space is inside the box so margin would have no effect.